# How to add radio buttons and checkBox in the same ListPreference in android?

Tags: android

HI,

How can i add, 4-radiobuttons and 2-checkBoxes in the same ListPreference in Android PreferenceScreen in android ? Need Help.
Thanks in adv.

rgds,
Praween

Answer (score 0):

create a xml with 4 buttons and 2 checkboxes and where you want use layout inflater like.....

```
     @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.relative, null);
        Button button1 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        .........
            ........
            Button button4 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button4);
            same for Checkbox  

        return view;
    }
```